# How to count the number of updated row

Tags: c#, .net, ms-access

I have an access database, and I do this query :

```
OleDatabase OleDB = new OleDatabase("MyDatabase");
string comando = "UPDATE ANAGRAFICA SET DENOMINAZIONE='" + aziendaValue["nome"] + "', INDIRIZZO='" + aziendaValue["indirizzo"] + "' WHERE PIVA='" + aziendaValue["piva"] + "'";
OleDB.oleComando(comando);
```

How can I check how many rows (0 to n) the query update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% on this since I haven't touched MS Access in a while, but I'm pretty sure that with ExecuteNonQuery you get the number of updated records, for example:

```
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE SomeTable SET SomeColumn='SomeValue'", SomeConnection);
int updated_records_count = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use [OleDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7shabkb8%28v=VS.100%29.aspx). It returns the number of affected rows.

Answer (score 0):

First thing you can do is:
"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ANAGRAFICA WHERE PIVA="+aziendaValue["piva"].
It takes a query more, but it should actually work and if you don't have problems with efficiency doing it is safe for sure!

Comment: But it could be WRONG -- what if there were 100 rows already with that value, and your UPDATE updated 10 more? This would tell you that 110 records were updated, when, in fact, only 10 were. The other answers are the correct answer -- every database engine has a RecordsAffected property that is available after you run a query that updates data, and that's precisely what its purpose is.